# How can you center a list inside of a nav

Tags: html, css, nav

I know a lot of people ask this but nothing that I tried has worked. I have tried everything I can find on the internet and nothing has helped. Can anyone help me figure out why my navbar is not centering? Any help is greatly appreciated! Here is the code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/b2zupssae2cly4d/AAC1mAoiNpMVnFX6jSUjrYb5a?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body{ /* display: flex; */}

```
li{display:inline}

nav{ width: 98%;
justify-content: center;}
```